# What if bounty is of +200 points?

Tags: discussion, bounty, daily-reputation-limit

I am curious of something here. If someone successfully earns a bounty of, let's say `+300` points and daily reputation limit `200` points, what will happen?

Is user gets `200` max point because that is the reputation limit for daily basis?

Or is this the exceptional case and the user will get `+300` points and after that he/she will not earn any point for the day?

What does the Stack Overflow rules say about this particular situation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bounties are not counted as part of the daily limit:

> As a special bonus, any reputation you earn from being awarded a bounty is exempt from the daily reputation cap.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Comment: so you are saying  that he still have 200 reputation limit available even if he earned 300 reputation points and he can still earn 300+200 =500 points? is it not affect at all to your daily reputation points?